# Visual studio test runner - criteria is filtering all tests

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild, test-runner, visual-studio-test-runner

Using VS 2013 and TFS 2013, I have 4 unit tests but I want a TFS build to run only one of them. For this I have assigned `[TestCategory("bvt")]` as an attribute of the method.

[image]

I edit the build definition, and within the "Add/Edit Test Run" dialog I give a value for "Test case filter:" of "TestCategory=bvt"

[image]

With the filter added, no tests are executed. If I remove the filter then a team build using "ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml" result in all 4 tests being executed.
I've tried wrapping the filter in quotes etc but haven't been able to get it to work - where am I going wrong?

Comment: Given `[TestMethod]` this seems to be MSTest as opposed to NUnit, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MS Test. More detail here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d187aeb9-eac1-4f24-81f4-de0b153b0bc2/visual-studio-test-runner-criteria-is-filtering-all-tests?forum=tfsbuild#9a3cc591-ec84-4706-967f-9b9c32a93048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reverting back to using the old default.xaml rather the the new TfsDefault.xaml