# MS Build TestCategory Filter not working

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-test-runner

**Environment**

- TFS2013.Update 2  12.0.30324.0
- C#
- Visual Studio 2013
- Visual Studio Test Runner
- Gated Check-In

**Problem**

As shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx) I decorated my TestMethod like

```
[TestCategory("Gated"), TestMethod()]
```

As shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138.aspx#Runner_VS_Filter) I filtered, like

```
TestCategory=Gated
```

When I build without any filter, the TestRun run successfully with all unit tests. But when I tried to filter over TestCaterory, no TestRun started at all.

**I tried without success ...**
... to put the filter in quotation:

```
"TestCategory=Gated"
```

... to separate the attributes:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Gated")]
```

... a similar question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799259/visual-studio-test-runner-criteria-is-filtering-all-tests), but I can't revert back to using the old default.xaml.

... I found just one warning in the build log under "Run Visual Studio Test Runner for Test Sources": "Dependent Assembly Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed of C:\Builds2\56\614\bin\External\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.dll not found. Can be ignored if not a NUnit project."
-> I added the reference to Newtonsoft.Json in every single NUnit-Project in all the solutions, that were build during the gated check-in - also without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the TestCategory, but another pretty simple one:
The unittest-project in which the “broken” testmethod resides was not part of ”projects to Build” of the Build Definition.